# How to bind to layoutBounds in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `Group` of objects which has some `Bounds`. I would like another object to follow the `Bounds`, so that whenever the group is expanded or shrinked, the object relocates to match the new `Bounds`. I figured, I need to bind `object.startXProperty()` and `object.startYProperty()` somehow to the value of `group.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() / getMinY()`. But these are not Observable, only `group.getLayoutBounds()` is.

How can I map the observability of the bounds to a `DoubleProperty`?

Comment: What about `layouX` and `layoutY`? (just make sure the Node in question is not `managed`)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html "A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not directly resizable."

Comment: @n247s: ```layoutX``` seems to contain negation of the value I need:  ```-getLayoutBounds.minX()```. Also I need to get other properties, like maxX(), or width, but they seem to be missing.

Comment: @Steve: I do not want to directly resize a Group, but to modify position of another object, as the Group is resized.

Comment: @PiotrG what is triggering the resizing of the group? is it the resizing of another component or of the stage?

Comment: I have two ScrollPanes. One contains the Group with various objects, that get resized, and the ScrollPane resizes as well. The second ScrollPane should follow the size of the first one. So I created dummy objects in its Group, whose only purpose is to resize the Group. Now I want to bind the position of the dummy objects to the Bounds of the Group in the first ScrollPane

Comment: can you just bind the width and height properties of the second scrollpane to the first?

Comment: The width and height of the scrollpane is fixed. I am adjusting the content which I scroll through.

Comment: `Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> node.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), node.layoutBoundsProperty());`.